# How to extend the Compose key

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, compose-key

I was looking for a way to extend the compose key (from tweaks) ability to be able to type arbitrary Unicode characters with custom key combinations.

ex. *compose_key + 'l' + 'a' + 'm' = 'λ'*

Answer (score 4):

I had this question myself and found an answer eventually (thanks to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/tuki6t/extending_the_compose_key/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

There is a rather simple way to extend the compose key.

You simply have to create the file `~/.XCompose` and put your new key combinations in there.

*Example of my XCompose file*:

```
> cat .XCompose 
include "%L"

# Math symbols
<Multi_key> <p> <i>                 : "π"   U03C0    # GREEK SMALL LETTER PI
<Multi_key> <S> <i> <g>             : "∑"   U2211  # Sigma


# Misc symbols
<Multi_key> <asterisk> <asterisk>   : "•"   U2022  # bullet point


# Agda symbols
<Multi_key> <T> <o> <p>             : "⊤"   U22A4  # Down Tack/Top
<Multi_key> <B> <o> <t>             : "⊥"   U22A5  # Up Tack/Bot

> …
```

You just need to add them in there, I use [This Site](https://unicode-table.com/en/) to find the UNICODE value of the character, in case anyone wants a site, though there are many alternative ways to find it.

Comment: Note you can even define snippets this way, i.e. `<Multi_key> <t> <y>                  : "thank you"`.

Comment: There is also a [github repo with ready to use XCompose file with lots of combinations](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose/blob/master/dotXCompose) you might be interested in.